# Avoid activity leak using scope dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, dagger-2

First to start with the my project architecture, I am using MVP and Dagger 2 for dependency injection.

I have been exploring scopes in dagger and my question is to better understand scope in context with Activity.

I have an activity(view) leak through presenter despite using activity scope.

As I am new to dagger and I feel I am missing something.

I am assuming that scope should handle my view to null when activity is destroyed(though right now do not understand how it will).Is my assumption right? if yes what I am doing wrong, else is it possible to avoid view leak using dagger? I know about the detachView approach, just curious if we can achieve the same thing using dagger 2.

P.S: I came to know about the leak through leakCanary.

Following is my code

LoginActivity.class

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoginContract.View {


    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    @Inject
    LoginPresenter presenter;

    private LoginComponent loginComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    createComponent();
    initViews();
    }

   private void createComponent() {
    loginComponent = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getRepositoryComponent()
            .COMPONENT(new LoginPresenterModule(this));
    loginComponent.inject(this);
}

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    loginComponent = null;
}
```

LoginPresenterModule.class

```
@Module
public class LoginPresenterModule {

private final LoginContract.View view;

public LoginPresenterModule(LoginContract.View view) {
    this.view = view;
}


@Provides
@ActivityScoped
public LoginContract.View providesView(){
    return view;
}
}
```

LoginComponent.class

```
@ActivityScoped
@Subcomponent(modules = LoginPresenterModule.class)
public interface LoginComponent {

  void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
}
```

LoginPresenter.class

```
@ActivityScoped
public class LoginPresenter implements LoginContract.Presenter {

private static final String TAG = "LoginPresenter";
private LoginContract.View view;

private DataRespository dataRespository;

@Inject
LoginPresenter(LoginContract.View view, DataRespository dataRespository) {
    this.view = view;
    this.dataRespository = dataRespository;
}


@Override
public void initTest(String testNo) {

    view.showProgressIndicator();
    dataRespository.sendTest(testNo, new DataSource.onResponseCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void obj) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NotNull ErrorWrapper error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError: ");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void start() {

}
```

}

DataRespositoryComponent.class

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,modules = 
DataRespositoryModule.class)
public interface DataRepositoryComponent {

LoginComponent COMPONENT(LoginPresenterModule loginPresenterModule);
}
```

Basically, view is leaked while making network call.
My leakcanary stack:
[image]

Comment: Could you include the trace / information from leak canary as to what leaks from where?

Comment: just did. check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This activity leaking has nothing to do with Dagger nor can Dagger help to prevent it.

The problem here lies with `dataRespository.sendTest(..anonymousCallback..)` where you add a callback to receive a result.

Anonymous classes as well as non-static inner classes will keep a reference to their enclosing object. In your case the callback keeps a reference to the presenter, which keeps a reference to the view, which keeps a reference to the Activity (this is what LeakCanary shows).

Since the callback is alive until it receives a response or an error, if your Activity were to be destroyed before your callback finishes, it will leak.

---

To fix your issue you need to either stop or unregister your callbacks, or remove the reference to the Activity. In this case it would probably be enough to set `view = null` in your presenter when the Activity gets destroyed to prevent the Activity from leaking.

Just make sure to check if the view is null before accessing it in your callback.

Comment: Shouldn't the view object live as long as the activity since it is activity scoped? Or is it like dagger is not responsible for killing the object?

Comment: @farhanpatel dagger only creates the object. The garbage collector won't collect it since okHttp is still referencing it

Comment: Thank you, now that you've explained it seems obvious!. :D

Comment: @farhanpatel why you have a view in your presenter? view should be in activity, thats the whole purpose of MVP!